# Highlighting of titles on main page

Tags: support, questions, user-interface, favorite-tag

Why are some question titles highlighted on the main page, while most are not? I had thought perhaps it was because they had been viewed by my computer, but that seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 5):

Questions titles are highlighted when one or more of their tags are in your "favorite tags" list.

@Jake and @msh210 have pointed out something I didn't know in the comments: questions with tags that you frequent are also highlighted if you have no favorite tags.

Comment: Huh? I haven't got any "favorite tags" (that I know of)!

Comment: Hmm, is it the entire background of the question's title, or the text itself that is highlighted?

Comment: The background. The entire strip behind the title.

Comment: Then you've got favorited tags. Check directly under the community bulletin board on the front page.

Comment: I've skimmed the main page, and it seems that all the questions with the Halacha tag are highlighted for me. But it's not my favorite (I checked that, too; when I click the tag and can view all the Halacha-tagged questions, they're not highlighted).

Comment: @SethJ, If you have not specified favorite tags, the system will choose them for you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131309

Comment: It chooses favorite tags for you if you haven't picked any. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88351.

Comment: I see that it is listed under "Frequent" tags. Hmm, I'm not sure how I feel about this? It could be useful, but up until now it's just made me crazy.

Comment: See the link I link to above, or the one jake links to, for a workaround.